# Issue With Adding Inner Class Object to ArrayList

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist

I have a client which sends a TestEllipse, which extends `Ellipse2D.Double`, to the server. The server wraps the ellipse in an ArrayList, calls its `updatePosition` method, which adds 10 to the x-coordinate of the ellipse, and sends the list back to the client.

When the x-coordinate of the ellipse equals or exceeds 100, the ellipse should be added to `removeList`, and it is... but it isn't. In the `updatePosition` method, when I print the size of `removeList`, this is output:

```
0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

So the ellipse is indeed being added to the list (albeit multiple times, which is irrelevant). But in the `main` method, it's as if the ellipse is not being added at all since printing the size of `removeList` produces this output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I thought that the change was not being reflected across threads, so I tried marking `removeList` as volatile, but it didn't help.

I also attempted creating an accessor method that returned `removeList`, but this did not work either.

How can I add the ellipse to `removeList` so that it can be accessed from the `main` method?

On the server side:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<TestClient.TestEllipse> list = new ArrayList<TestClient.TestEllipse>();
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(31362);
            Socket socket = listener.accept();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            while (true) {
                try {
                    TestClient.TestEllipse addEllipse = (TestClient.TestEllipse) ois.readObject();
                    if (addEllipse != null)
                        list.add(addEllipse);
                    TestClient.TestEllipse removeEllipse = (TestClient.TestEllipse) ois.readObject();
                    if (removeEllipse != null)
                        list.remove(removeEllipse);
                    for (TestClient.TestEllipse ellipse : list)
                        ellipse.updatePosition();
                    oos.writeObject(list);
                    oos.reset();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And on the client side:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.*;

public class TestClient implements Serializable {
    static volatile List<TestEllipse> removeList = new ArrayList<TestEllipse>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<TestEllipse> list = new ArrayList<TestEllipse>();
            TestEllipse t = new TestClient().new TestEllipse(50, 250);
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 31362);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            while (true) {
                try {
                    oos.writeObject(t);
                    t = null;
                    // System.out.print(removeList.size() + " ");
                    if (removeList.size() > 0)
                        oos.writeObject(removeList.remove(0));
                    else
                        oos.writeObject(null);
                    list = (List<TestEllipse>) ois.readObject();
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class TestEllipse extends java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double implements Serializable {
        int x, y;

        public TestEllipse(int x, int y) {
            super(x,y,10,10);
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void updatePosition() {
            if ((x += 10) >= 100)
                removeList.add(this);
            //System.out.print(removeList.size() + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate processes running. Each thread is in it's own process. They do not share removeList object defined in TestClient. When in TestServer you call ellipse.updatePosition() it executes on the ellipse from the list. That list has been recreated in TestServer#main method's scope and has no connection to the removeList which is defined in TestClient#main.

The TestEllipse itself could be modified to have it's state regarding removal:

```
public static class TestEllipse
        extends java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double
        implements Serializable 
{
    int x, y;
    boolean forRemove;

    public void setForRemove(boolean forRemove)
    {
        this.forRemove = forRemove;
    }

    public boolean isForRemove()
    {
        return forRemove;
    }

    public TestEllipse(int x, int y) 
    {
        super(x,y,10,10);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void updatePosition() 
    {
        if ((x += 10) >= 100)
        {
            setForRemove(true);
        }
    } 
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("{x:%d,y:%d,forRemove:%b}",x,y,isForRemove());
    }
}
```

Then when you have a list, remove ellipses that are marked for removal:

```
for (ListIterator<TestEllipse> li = list.listIterator() ; li.hasNext();)
{
    TestEllipse elipse = (TestEllipse)li.next();
    if (elipse.isForRemove())
    {           
        li.remove();
    }
}
```